# How would I write a script that will fetch a site's table to embed in your site?

Tags: scripting, embed, html

Ok, here is what I want to do.  Given the name of a baseball player, I would like to automatically import his stats from baseball-reference.com and embed in my site.

They already allow you to do this manually by providing you with a 'share' button that will give you the html of the stats table.  I would just like to automate this process.

I have no idea on where to start on something like this.  Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: You should start by reading the EULA of baseball-reference.com and be sure that automating this is even allowed on their site.

Comment: you can refer to this page http://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.shtml. What you're attempting to do is against their terms of use.

Comment: The site you found is off-limits, but in general you want a site that allows free access to their data via an API, or Application Programming Interface ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440379/what-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-an-api ). For possible open sources of data, see http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/is-there-an-api-or-global-database-for-sports-events-that-is-used-by-famous-spor . You probably want to use Javascript and jQuery to interact with the API and  make a request for JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I never thought about this being against their EULA since they were letting you do it manually.  Oh well.