# How to connect a phonegap app to a database in my hosting website?

Tags: php, mysql, cordova

I have made a phonegap app and i want to know how to connect it to the database in my hosting website and add data?

Comment: Using API / Web service

Comment: can you explain briefly plz?

Answer (score 0):

Activate Internet permission and then use an AJAX like function to call a WEB API. This could be a script hosted from your hosting company which when called returns the data which you require in your app. This should ideally be in a standard format like JSON or XML.

Read more about REST APIs.

Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) to learn about REStfull APIs and Services.

See [this](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/12/on-third-day-of-phonegapping-getting.html) post from 2011 which pulls a REST API.

Comment: Thanks... ill see to it!

Comment: accept the answer and upvote if you found it usefull!

Answer (score 0):

API / Web Service is a code which can be written in any server side language like `PHP`. This script will communicate with with your Database.

These API/ Web service can be called from client, client can be a Web App / Web Site/ Mobile app, using `HTTP METHODS` (POST, GET etc). This API request will give response to the particular client with expected result (i.e. fetching data from database etc) and the response format can be JSON/ XML.

For more information you can **[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440379/what-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-an-api)**.

Comment: Thanks...ill see to it!