# What is the meaning of "API of module"?

Tags: web

i know the individual  meaning of the terms "module" & "API" but as these were used here ,I could not follow`enter code here`

Here’s an eg in Node.js:

The API of a Math.js module:

exports.square = square;
Now, here is how another program could use the Math module’s API without knowing how it internally works:

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the meaning of an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440379/what-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-an-api)

Comment: What does "API of module" mean.I mean API enable interaction between the programs whereas module is just a software component which encapsulate various programs and provide functionality ,but how does they are related to each other in "API of module"