# Get product given date

Tags: javascript

How to properly get the date 3 days before the given, if I have a format like **07/21/2017 8:30 AM** , this is because I use the format of Eonasdan DateTime Picker. But when I try to minus it with 3 days I got **Fri Jul 21 2017 08:24:14 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)** as my value but my desired output should be the same format like **07/21/2017 8:30 AM**. How can I get that the value even I follow my format?

My codes:

```js
var d =new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM');
var yesterday = new Date(d.getTime() - (96*60*60));
alert(yesterday);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend taking a look at moment.js, it will make your life much easier when dealing with dates in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract days from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I think my question is little bit the same but totally different, the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript is just asking for subtracting current date into certain value without any format where if my question has a format to follow. Therefore, I can say my question is unique, not the same or no duplicate. @Champ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function formatDate(d) {
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();
    
        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    
        date = [month, day, year].join('/');
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return date+" "+strTime;
}
var d =new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM');
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
var yesterday = formatDate(d);
alert(yesterday);
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks this is the one I'm looking for. Thanks for the help @Kishor V

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
var date = new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM'); // get
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 3);
console.log(date.toString());
```

Basically, it takes the current day with [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and uses [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) to update the time to 3 days in the past.

If you want to format your date, look into [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) like @Robert said. You could use something like:

```
moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

More information on the `Date` class [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and moment documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/docs).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var d = new Date();
var d =new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM');
var yesterday = d;
yesterday.setDate(d.getDate()-3);
alert(yesterday);
```

Comment: yes, sorry, I was slower to answer him in comparison with others. When I clicked on his question none posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply **subtract days** from the Date E.g `d.getDate() - 3`

```js
var d =new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM');
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
alert(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to  use `setDate` function on `Date` class to change the date part of a date variable

```js
    var d =new Date('07/21/2017 8:30 AM');
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
    console.debug(d);
```

Comment: `setDate()` isn't an API, it's a built-in class method.

Comment: @brennanenanen Does this sound correct - `setDate API on Date class`? I know calling it a method is certainly correct which you've advised.

Comment: API stands for application programming interface. API's are used to talk between applications and are not built-in classes of something like js.

Comment: What you've said is certainly correct but that API is very applicable to public  methods of a class as well. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7440416/465053).

Comment: Hmm, I guess. Stil, it isn't talking to an application and it's not using a programming interface.