# I have 3 questions that cause me to conflict and not understand their terminology

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angularjs, api

I am new to Angular and I have an initial understanding of the special basics and these questions are facing me and I want to understand them well.
I've been reading around trying to understand what RESTful API is all about.

1- In Angular, can we say about (Fetch Data Using HTTP Client With Angular) it is an Api or Rest

2 - Using Json obj taken from a page that gives us the obj and using the data in it and showing it in my web page Can it be called using api

3- Is the creation of the API related to the tasks of front-end or back-end in the case of dealing with the framework of Angular

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about what an API is. API (stands for Application Programming Interface) allows one program to communicate with another program. An API and it's specification are basically a set of functionality that one program allows other programs to use. It isn't necessarily related to HTTP. The terms REST and API are NOT disjoint. REST only formalizes the set of specifications. A million different explanations of what an API is can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440379/what-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-an-api

Comment: yes you are right.. and thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

I will answer simple to you and shortly:

1. RESTful transfers a representation of the state of the resource to the requester or endpoint. Check it out for more info here [REST API](https://restfulapi.net/)
2. API stands for (application programming interface) is a connection between computers. It is a type of software interface, offering services to other pieces of software.

HttpClient in Angular is a module helping developers to do http requests to that API for accessing/manipulating recourses.

Keep going, hope to help you a little bit.